# Php library for getting polygon points from image?

Tags: images, php

I need to get programmatically polygon points coordinates from image.

Here is an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzHkt.jpg

Requirements:

1. Take image with transparent background and some colored polygon on it
2. Run this library on image.
3. Get polygon points coordinates in pixels.

I don't know anything about software available for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be useful for someone - there is no native realization of this, written on php.

But there is very useful program - [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/) - which can be lauched from `shell_exec`.

It helped me with my problems.